# How to validate uniqueness on multiple columns in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

Right now I have this for each column as a "Data Validation":

```
=COUNTIF($E$2:$E,"="&E1) < 2
```

That makes sure there are no duplicates. But now I am separating the words into different columns (nouns in column 1, verbs in column 2, adj in col 3, etc). How can I validate uniqueness across all these columns? That is, they are all just "words", how can I verify there are no duplicate words?

[image]

Ideally it would show the little red triangle, or highlight whole cell red somehow, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply conditional formatting to range A2:D with the next custom formula:

> =COUNTIF($A$2:$D,A2)>1

See it working in the next image:
[image]

Here you have the sample sheet ;)
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OcbrdhWS-gP_leGbx0wh8CM85wPvjgMINNQipJywe_M/edit?usp=sharing